# Can I sample with a mean and standard deviation of a asymmetric distribution

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, sample

I have 166,796 values which contain a lot of zeros (see chart). I was wondering if I could sample using the mean and standard deviation of the data rather than sample the actual data?  Since the data is clearly not Normal, I wasn't sure of the standard deviation actually applied here.

The situation is as follows:
The data represents a baseline for FY 17/18 from which I need to make changes and see how those changes impact the future.  There are four variables in the data set which are based on points that our military use to buy clothing.  The variables are:  Unused Points (determined at end of the FY); Deducted Points (Excess points over a limit that a member can Carryover into the next FY); Carry over points, which are used for next year; and, Used points, which the member is available to use to buy clothing.

The baseline allows the member to use up to 800 point, carry over up to 300, and whatever they don't use (Unused) are lost (Deducted) if it's more than the carry over.

I need to make changes to the use and carry over limits changing them from 800 to 600 and 300 to 200, respectively.  I want to be able to modify the baseline data and see how this impacts the overall system going forward.

[image]

Comment: How would you sample using the mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Also, you already have data. Why are you sampling?

Comment: Do you want to generate data that have same distribution?

Comment: The data represents a baseline from which I need to make adjustments and forecast into the future based on these changes.  I just assumed I needed to sample to generate various paths forward and specify a confidence Interval to the forecasts.  I want to generate data that has the same shape as the baseline distribution.

Comment: Then, as  suggested by the comments, sample from the data you have.

Comment: I will, but for my own education could you tell me if it's correct to also (if necessary) to sample from the mean and SD of a highly asymmetric distribution?